# Perform csv sanitisation in linear time

Tags: pandas, performance, file-io, big-o, python-3.7

I'm using the [HTC](https://htcinstrument.com/avm-06.html) anemometer and it gives me data in the following order, where in two of the columns are merged into one and there's some useless data I want to exclude.
The data looks like below

```
"NO.","T&RH","DATA","UNIT","TIME"
1," 27�C 70.5%",0,"m/s","30-11-2020\15:33:34"
2," 27�C 70.5%",0,"m/s","30-11-2020\15:33:35"
3," 27�C 70.5%",0,"m/s","30-11-2020\15:33:36"
4," 27�C 70.5%",0,"m/s","30-11-2020\15:33:37"
...
...
```

When I try to load it into a pandas data-frame, there's all kind of weird errors.

I've come up with the following code to clean the data and export it as a df.

```py
import pandas as pd
def _formathtc(text_data:list) ->pd.DataFrame:
  data = []
  for l in rawdata:
    d = []
    l = l.split(",")
    try:
      _,t,h = l[1].strip('"').split(" ")
      d.append(t.replace("°C","")) 
      d.append(h.replace("%",""))
      d.append(l[2])
      d.append(l[-1].strip('\n'))
      data.append(d)
    except Exception as e:
      pass
  df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
  df.columns=['temp','relhum','data','time']
  return df

def gethtc(filename:str)->pd.DataFrame:
  text_data = open(filename, "r", encoding="iso-8859-1").readlines()
  return _formathtc(text_data)

df = gethtc(somefilename)
```

My problem is that the above shown operations operate in linear time, i.e., as the file grows in size more is the time take to extract out the info and get that data-frame.

How can I make it more efficient?

Comment: @anon01 the data is stored/logged into a csv file through a software that came with the device. However, I'm trying to improve the efficiency of what happens after, ie., the trim, split and re-forming another df out of the original file. let's not consider the `read` bottleneck. Can the above function be made any better in terms of say performance? will surely profile the code

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pd.read_csv` in place of the `DataFrame` constructor here. There are a ton of options (including `encoding`, and `engine` `quotechar` which may be helpful). At least pandas does all the parsing for you, and probably has better performance (esp. setting `engine="c"`).  If this doesn't help with performance, I'm not sure there is a better native pandas option:

```
df = pd.read_csv("htc.csv", engine="c")
df["TIME"] = pd.to_datetime(df.TIME.str.replace("\\", " "))
df["T&RH"] = df['T&RH'].str.replace("�", "")
```

output:

```
   NO.        T&RH  DATA UNIT                TIME
0    1   27C 70.5%     0  m/s 2020-11-30 15:33:34
1    2   27C 70.5%     0  m/s 2020-11-30 15:33:35
2    3   27C 70.5%     0  m/s 2020-11-30 15:33:36
3    4   27C 70.5%     0  m/s 2020-11-30 15:33:37
```

The post-processing is optional of course, but I don't think should slow things down much.

Comment: I did use the `read_csv` method and got the output as show above, again, the linear time O(n). Just wondering if it could any better. Thanks for the answer though.